# css toggle not working properly in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here in my app the function 'todoCompleted' is invoked when list item or checkbox is clicked. When i click the checkbox the code is not running correctly, the style is applied only once, I'm not able to toggle it. 
Used : "todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'" in li element.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

  

          constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
        todo:[]
      };
    };

    entertodo(keypress){
      var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
      if( keypress.charCode == 13 )

      {
        this.setState({
          todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false})

        });
        this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
      };
    };
    todo(todo,i){
      return (
        <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
          <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}>
            <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
            <div key={todo.id}  className="item">
              {todo.Value}
              <div className="Button">
              <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    };

    remove(i){
      this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
      this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
    };
    todoCompleted(i){
       var todo=this.state.todo;
       {
         todo[i].checked =true;
         this.setState({
           todo:this.state.todo
         });
       }
     };
    allCompleted=()=>{
      var todo = this.state.todo;
      var _this = this
      todo.forEach(function(item) {
       item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
       item.checked = !_this.state.finished
   })
   this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
    };

      render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
            <div className="lines"></div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
                <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">x</span>
              </div>
              <div className="mainapp">
                <ul>
                {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
      

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
    .line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the state to true whenever it get click, so i replaced that to conditional value.

```
todo[i].checked =todo[i].checked?false:true;
```

i.e. if set to true, then change it to false, otherwise make it true

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
        todo:[]
       };
    };

    entertodo(keypress){
      var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
      if( keypress.charCode == 13 )

      {
        this.setState({
          todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, checked:false})

        });
        this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
      };
    };
    todo(todo,i){
      return (
        <li className={todo.checked===true? 'line':'newtodo'}>
          <div onClick={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}>
            <input type="checkbox" className="option-input checkbox" checked={todo.checked} />
            <div key={todo.id}  className="item">
              {todo.Value}
              <div className="Button">
              <span className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    };

    remove(i){
      this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
      this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
    };
    todoCompleted(i){
       var todo=this.state.todo;
        //removed curly braces as not used and added contion to set true or false 
         todo[i].checked =todo[i].checked?false:true;
         this.setState({
           todo:this.state.todo
         });
       
     };
    allCompleted=()=>{
      var todo = this.state.todo;
      var _this = this
      todo.forEach(function(item) {
       item.className = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo" : "line"
       item.checked = !_this.state.finished
   })
   this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished})
    };

      render() {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
            <div className="lines"></div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
                <span onClick={this.allCompleted}id="all">x</span>
              </div>
              <div className="mainapp">
                <ul>
                {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
      

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.line {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}
.newtodo{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: can u explain it a bit, how **todo[i].checked?false:true;** is working here

Comment: when you add a new todo its value is false, so when you click it first time, it comes to check if see if its false, it sets the value to true and when you uncheck it, it comes to function and now the value is true so it changes it to false todo[i].checked =   todo[i].checked?false:true is equivalent to  if( todo[i].checked==true) { todo[i].checked=false } else {todo[i].checked = true}